# Ссылка с изображением слева от текста

Tags: html, изображения, css

Здравствуйте ! Подскажите, как сделать ссылку с изображением, чтобы изображение было фоном и слева, а текст справа и выравнивался по высоте. Как на [этом](http://piccy.info/view3/5643306/59021de72d85aba8112b24698fba081e/) изображении. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример:

```css
.custom::before {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}

.custom {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a class="custom" href="#">Super Link!</a>
```

Можно проще, если не обязательно делать задним фоном картинку:

```css
.custom::before {
  content: url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.custom {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a class="custom" href="#">Super Link!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение, при котором область между картиной и текстом будет тоже кликабельной

```
.custom {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/30x30') no-repeat;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```